# d3js appending text - transition

Tags: d3.js, label, transition

I have a simple "Effective date label" and i want the text to change as it transitions:

sorted_effective_date is a simple array: [10 Jun 2012, 25 Jun 2012, 30 Jun 2012, etc]

```
for (i = 0; i < sorted_effective_date.length; i++) {

    l.selectAll("text")
        .data(sorted_effective_date)
       .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(sorted_effective_date[0])
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('y', 15)
        .attr('x', 150)
        .attr('font-size', '25px')
        .attr('fill', '#1c3062');

    l.selectAll("text")
        .data(sorted_effective_date)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .text(sorted_effective_date[i]);

}
```

The value of the label just stays at value i=0, it doesn't change. Am i missing anything or doing anything wrong?

Please note that when i debug the code, i does change and the loop works properly.

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? Error messages? Not expected behaviour?

Comment: it doesn't do anything, the value shown just stays on i=0.